# SQL query using PHP not recognizing results between dates properly

Tags: php, sql

These expressions works perfectly:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_SUITE_INSPECTION 
WHERE QA_DATE = '$s_date'; returns the data for the requested date

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_SUITE_INSPECTION 
WHERE QA_DATE = '$s_date' OR QA_DATE='$e_date'"; returns the data for the two required dates.
```

I can't figure out the reason for this statement not to work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_SUITE_INSPECTION 
WHERE QA_DATE BETWEEN '$s_date' AND '$e_date'";
```

The SQL database has the QA_DATE as VARCHAR.

The data returned is always incomplete or with no results at all.

Example: The database has data for the following dates:

```
2/4/18  
2/5/18  
2/7/18  
2/8/18  
2/9/18  
2/11/18  
2/15/18  
2/16/18  
2/18/18  

The results for s_date=2/4/18 and e_date=2/18/18 are none.

The result for s_date=2/4/18 and e_date=2/4/18 is correct.

The result for s_date=2/18/18 and e_date=2/18/18 is correct.

The results for s_date=2/4/18 and e_date=2/5/18 are correct.

The results for s_date=2/4/18 and e_date=2/7/18 are correct.

The results for s_date=2/4/18 and e_date=2/8/18 are correct.

The results for s_date=2/4/18 and e_date=2/9/18 are correct.

The results for s_date=2/4/18 and e_date=2/11/18 are none.

The result for s_date=2/11/18 and e_date=2/11/18 is correct.

The results for s_date=Any date and e_date=2/9/18 are correct.
```

Why is the query not picking up results for dates greater than 2/11/18?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You shoul check your date format on database. Usually it is "yyyy-mm-dd" not "d/m/yy"

Comment: The database shows the dates as I presented them in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the database column is a varchar, the data is being compared alphabetically. Alphabetically, `2/11/18` is the earliest value, so that's why you're seeing the results you're seeing. This is one reason why it's always best to use a date column type for dates.

You can probably make it work using https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date or similar. But if you can change the data set that would be a much better solution.

Comment: There has to be something else. The point is not that the data shows in order or not.  The problem is that there are dates not showing. I just ran the same query using s_date 2/1/18 and e_date 2/18/18 and it showed the results from 2/11/18 to 2/18/18 only :(

Comment: What other results would you expect there? Remember this is an _alphabetical_ comparison, not a _numeric_ one. `2/4/18` is alphabetically after `2/11/18` in the same way that `2/d/18` is after `2/aa/18`.

Comment: I see it now!  Thanks for the clarification. I selected your answers as the correct one. Thanks a lot. Now I'll figure out how to handle the data in order to get what I need.